# Why is my ConfigurationElement not reading its values from the app.config?

Tags: .net, configuration, c#-4.0

I'm using the System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement to represent some data in my app.config. It correctly detects that the section is there (if the section isn't it throws an error), but it is never correctly populated. For the Queues I only ever get an empty collection, and for the sleepTime I only ever get 500.

here is the relevant app.config section:

```
<serviceBroker sleepTime="1000"> 
  <queues>  
     <queue name="TestQueue" priority="1"/>
  </queues>
</serviceBroker>
```

here is the complete app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,Castle.Windsor" />
    <section name="SAM.Configuration.Data" type="SAM.Configuration.Data.DataConfigurationSection, SAM.Configuration"/>
    <section name="NHibernate.Caches.MemCache" type="NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheSectionHandler,NHibernate.Caches.MemCache" />
</configSections>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<castle/>
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString=""/>
    <add name="AuthSqlServer" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
<SAM.Configuration.Data>
    <mage MaxThreads="1" SmtpHost="qa" SmtpPort="25">
        <Tasks/>
    </mage>
    <serviceBroker sleepTime="1000">
        <queues>
            <queue name="TestQueue" priority="1"/>
        </queues>
    </serviceBroker>
    <databases>
        <database name="BusinessDomain" defaultConnectionName="">
            <connections>
                <connection>
                    <add key="name" value=""/>
                    <add key="assembly" value="SAM.Data.NHibernateProvider"/>
                    <add key="type" value="SAM.Data.NHibernateProvider.RepositoryManager"/>
                    <add key="configurationFile" value="Business.NHibernateSession.Config"/>
                    <add key="isEncrypted" value="FALSE" />
                </connection>
                <connection>
                    <add key="name" value=""/>
                    <add key="assembly" value="SAM.Data.NHibernateProvider"/>
                    <add key="type" value="SAM.Data.NHibernateProvider.RepositoryManager"/>
                    <add key="configurationFile" value="Business.NHibernateSession.Config"/>
                    <add key="isEncrypted" value="FALSE" />
                </connection>
            </connections>
        </database>
    </databases>
</SAM.Configuration.Data>
<NHibernate.Caches.MemCache configSource="nhibernate.memcache.config" />
</configuration>
```

And here is my ConfigurationElement:

```
public class ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement,
{
  [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceBrokerQueueElement), AddItemName = "queue")]
  [ConfigurationProperty("queues", IsRequired = true)]
  public ServiceBrokerQueueElementCollection Queues
  {
    get { return (ServiceBrokerQueueElementCollection)this["queues"]; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("sleepTime", DefaultValue = (int) 500, IsRequired = true)]
  public int SleepTime
  {
    get { return (int)this["sleepTime"]; }
  }
}
```

Here is my ConfigurationSection (I've stripped out a number of other elements that are working fine)

```
public class DataConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string SectionName = "SAM.Configuration.Data";

    private static DataConfigurationSection _configSection;

    [ConfigurationProperty("serviceBroker", IsRequired = false)]
    public ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement ServiceBroker
    {
        get
        {
            return (ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement)this["serviceBroker"];
        }
    }

    public static DataConfigurationSection Section
    {
        get
        {
            if (_configSection == null)
            {
                _configSection = ((DataConfigurationSection)(ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SectionName)));
            }

            return _configSection;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i'm assuming the ` at the end of the config is just a typo that occurred when typing it in stackoverflow?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'll clean that up

Comment: How is the configuration section defined?

Comment: erwin, the C# side or the app.config side?

Comment: @Dugan The class that inherits from ConfigurationSection.

Comment: @erwin done. Happy to add anything else you think might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it basically had nothing to do with the Configuration section stuff at all, I had everything wired up incorrectly in Castle.Windsor. It was always returning an empty instance of the ServiceBrokerConfiguration, instead of one loaded from the app.config.

Thanks for the help though everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your application configuration file contains the relevant configuration section declaration?  Something like the following is required to map your configuration section to the type that implements it.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SamConfigurationData" type="Namespace.DataConfigurationSection, AssemblyName"/>
  </configSections>

  <SamConfigurationData>
    <serviceBroker sleepTime="1000"> 
      <queues>  
        <queue name="TestQueue" priority="1"/>
      </queues>
    </serviceBroker>
  </SamConfigurationData>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It does: <section name="SAM.Configuration.Data" type="SAM.Configuration.Data.DataConfigurationSection, SAM.Configuration"/>

Comment: Also, I don't think you can have the `.` character in XML names, so `SAM.Configuration.Data` is unlikely to work as a configuration section element name.

Comment: And does your configuration have an element named `SAM.Configuration.Data` (or similar) to contain your `serviceBroker` configuration? (may have not seen my most recent edit)

Comment: The configuration works fine for a number of other elements, so I don't think the `.` character should be the issue. And yes, here let me put up my full app.config to avoid some confusion

Answer (score 0):

I did not see anything wrong, but I had to try it myself.  Here's the version I got working, and compare it to what you have (including the missing portions).  You can put a try / catch where it calls GetSection if you still see something horribly wrong happening.

app.Config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="SAM.Configuration.Data" type="Test.DataConfigurationSection, Test" />
  </configSections>

  <SAM.Configuration.Data>
    <serviceBroker sleepTime="1000">
      <queues>
        <queue name="TestQueue" priority="1"/>
      </queues>
    </serviceBroker>
  </SAM.Configuration.Data>
```

Configuration classes:

```
public class DataConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string SectionName = "SAM.Configuration.Data";

    private static DataConfigurationSection _configSection;

    [ConfigurationProperty("serviceBroker", IsRequired = false)]
    public ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement ServiceBroker
    {
        get
        {
            return (ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement)this["serviceBroker"];
        }
    }

    public static DataConfigurationSection Section
    {
        get
        {
            if (_configSection == null)
            {
                _configSection = ((DataConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SectionName)));
            }

            return _configSection;
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceBrokerConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceBrokerQueueElement), AddItemName = "queue")]
    [ConfigurationProperty("queues", IsRequired = true)]
    public ServiceBrokerQueueElementCollection Queues
    {
        get { return (ServiceBrokerQueueElementCollection)this["queues"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("sleepTime", DefaultValue = (int)500, IsRequired = true)]
    public int SleepTime
    {
        get { return (int)this["sleepTime"]; }
    }
}

public class ServiceBrokerQueueElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ServiceBrokerQueueElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ServiceBrokerQueueElement)element).Name;
    }

    public new ServiceBrokerQueueElement this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return (ServiceBrokerQueueElement)this.BaseGet(name);
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceBrokerQueueElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["name"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("priority", IsRequired = true)]
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this["priority"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["priority"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```